# Linux で syslog のログファイルが肥大化する問題を対策したい

Tags: linux

Ubuntu16.04で、Texファイルを作成していると、syslogファイルが膨張し過ぎて困っています。急に、PCの音が大きくなり、容量不足になります。
何か対策等分かる方いますか？
sudo cp -i /dev/null /var/log/syslog
として、容量を一時的に解消しても、またすぐに容量不足になります。
<追加>
ログを確認したところ、

```
gnome-session[1953]: page: Warning: font ‘rml’ not found, trying metric files instead
gnome-session[1953]: page: Error: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/dvips/rml.tfm: File corrupted, or not a TFM file
gnome-session[1953]: page: Warning: metric file for 'rml' not found, trying 'cmr10' instead
gnome-session[1953]: page:Error: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/dvips/rml.tfm: File corrupted, or not a TFM file
```

と複数出ていました。

```
apt list -- install "tex*"
```

の出力結果は以下のようになっています。

```
tex-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 6.04ubuntu1 all [インストール済み、自動]
tex-gyre/xenial,xenial 20150923-1 all
tex4ht/xenial 20090611-1.1build1 amd64
tex4ht-common/xenial,xenial 20090611-1.1build1 all
texi2html/xenial,xenial 1.82+dfsg1-5 all
texify/xenial,xenial 1.20-3 all
texinfo/xenial 6.1.0.dfsg.1-5 amd64
texinfo-doc-nonfree/xenial,xenial 6.1.0-2 all
texlive/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-base/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all [インストール済み]
texlive-bibtex-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-binaries/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2015.20160222.37495-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-extra-utils/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-font-utils/xenial,xenial,now 2015.20160320-1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-fonts-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-fonts-extra-doc/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-fonts-recommended/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-formats-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-full/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-games/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-generic-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-generic-recommended/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-htmlxml/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-humanities/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-humanities-doc/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-lang-african/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-all/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-arabic/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-chinese/xenial,xenial,now 2015.20160223-1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-lang-cjk/xenial,xenial,now 2015.20160223-1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-lang-cyrillic/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-czechslovak/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-english/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-european/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-french/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-german/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-greek/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-indic/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-italian/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-japanese/xenial,xenial,now 2015.20160223-1 all [インストール済み]
texlive-lang-korean/xenial,xenial,now 2015.20160223-1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-lang-other/xenial,xenial,now 2015.20160223-1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-lang-polish/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-portuguese/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-lang-spanish/xenial,xenial 2015.20160223-1 all
texlive-latex-base/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-latex-base-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all [インストール済み、自動]
texlive-latex-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-latex-extra-doc/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-latex-recommended/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-latex-recommended-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-luatex/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-math-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-metapost/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-metapost-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-music/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-omega/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-pictures/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-pictures-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texlive-plain-extra/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-pstricks/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-pstricks-doc/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-publishers/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-publishers-doc/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-science/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-science-doc/xenial,xenial 2015.20160320-1 all
texlive-xetex/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 all
texmaker/xenial 4.4.1-1.1 amd64
texmaker-data/xenial,xenial 4.4.1-1.1 all
texstudio/xenial 2.10.8+debian-1 amd64
texstudio-dbg/xenial 2.10.8+debian-1 amd64
texstudio-doc/xenial,xenial 2.10.8+debian-1 all
texstudio-l10n/xenial,xenial 2.10.8+debian-1 all
textdraw/xenial 0.2+ds-0+nmu1build1 amd64
textedit.app/xenial 4.0+20061029-3.4build2 amd64
texworks/xenial 0.5~svn1363-6build2 amd64
texworks-help-en/xenial,xenial 0.5~svn1363-6build2 all
texworks-scripting-lua/xenial 0.5~svn1363-6build2 amd64
texworks-scripting-python/xenial 0.5~svn1363-6build2 amd64
```

Comment: 何が原因でログが肥大化してるのか (syslog にどんなログが記録されているのか) を確認した方がよさそうです。

Comment: terminalなら `tail /var/log/syslog` などで, GUIならランチャーから `log`などとタイプして「ログ」起動できるので, 内容を確認し, 質問に情報追加してみてください。LaTeX扱う上で, **例えば**フォントがないというメッセージが大量に出てるならフォント追加すれば解決できるはず

Comment: ありがとうございます。　ログを確認しました。

Comment: `-- install` ではなく `--installed` です。スペース含まないこととスペルも違います。`apt`のサブコマンドとして `list`を指定し, オプション指定で `installed`。大抵の CLIのコマンドは, `-h` のようにハイフンに続けて 1文字, もしくは `--help` のように 2つのハイフンに続けて単語を指定します (すべてのコマンドがその形式という訳ではないが, 大抵はそんな感じ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

フォントが入ってなさそうな感じです。
似たようなフォントパスが存在するので, 試してみてはどうでしょうか？
(symbolic link の可能性もあるため)

パッケージ名: `texlive-lang-japanese`
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex-fonts/dvips/rml.tfm`
相違点

- (`ptex` ⇨ `ptex-fonts`)

参考: Ubuntu [パッケージ内容検索](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=rml.tfm&mode=exactfilename&suite=impish&arch=any)

パッケージ インストール方法

```
$ sudo apt install texlive-lang-japanese
```

---

##### 追記

別の回答にコメントが付いてそうだけど, 「URLとべない」が何を指しているのか不明。
((こちらに)通知来ないので, コメントは正しいところに指定したほうがよいです)

「パッケージ内容検索」なら https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=rml.tfm&mode=exactfilename&suite=impish&arch=any

---

`texlive-lang-japanese` パッケージはインストール済みということなので, パス指定を変更すればうまくいくかも？
`trying 'cmr10' instead` のメッセージが存在するということ … なので, それをインストールする方法もあります (`cmr10.tfm` であれば   `texlive-base` パッケージ)
(そもそも Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (5年前の環境) なので, 可能なら最新版にするのもありかも)

参考:

- ファイルが見つからない場合の対処法(dvipdfmx)  [https://texwiki.texjp.org/?dvipdfmx%2Fフォントの設定](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?dvipdfmx%2F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)
- フォントの埋め込みがうまく行かないときにチェックすること [https://astr.phys.saga-u.ac.jp/~funakubo/research/recipe/Jfont-embed.htm](https://astr.phys.saga-u.ac.jp/%7Efunakubo/research/recipe/Jfont-embed.htm)

とりあえず, LaTeX 環境として何をインストールしているのか, また, 何を動かしているのか(dvipdfmx ？)
… あまりに当初の質問とかけ離れるようであれば, 別の質問にする方がよいかもしれません

texlive系でインストールしているパッケージ一覧を見るには

```
$ apt list --installed "tex*"
```

---

`texlive-base` が入ってそうなのに, cmr10 が無いということであれば
Ubuntuを最新にする手段も考慮したほうがよいかも
それがだめなら, とりあえず無理にパスを通して, syslog 出さないようにする方法も

(もっといい方法があれば, そちらを … あまり良くない方法なので)

```
$ cd /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/
$ sudo ln -s ptex-fonts ptex
```

Comment: apt list -- install "tex*"の出力結果は上のようになっており, texlive-baseはありました。

Comment: @炎天下修羅 Ubuntuは結局, アップグレードできるのか無理なのか, 無理なのなら回答に示した対策は可能なのかどうか, 対策行ったのなら結果はどうだったのか … 結果を記してほしいのですが

Comment: 最終的に、syslogを出さないことで、解決しました。大学で、卒論に使うだけであり、大学でも、アップグレードしないように言われているため、やめました。その後は、仮想環境を使うつもりはないので問題ないと思います。何か、syslog を出さないことで起こる問題等があれば教えてくださると助かります。

Comment: @炎天下修羅 ログを取らないと何か問題が起きても分からないということです。例えば火災警報・ガス漏れ警報・防犯センサーすべて無効にしてる感じ。もう少しよい方法は一部だけ(該当する部分だけ)無効化。もっとよいのは(今回の場合)フォントパスが通るように設定すること

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。

Comment: 念のため: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
(捨てアカでないのなら, 他の質問するときに参考にする人もいるでしょう)

Answer (score -1):

このQ&Aが参考になりそうです。

[syslogのサイズを制限するにはどうすればよいですか？](https://ubuntu.buildwebhost.com/ja/q/26898)

Comment: > 調べてみたところ既にインストールされていました。texlive-lang-Japaneseは入っていました。

→ 何の話をしているのですか？コメント先をお間違えではないですか？

Comment: > URLとべないのでとべるようにしていただけると嬉しいです。 → 意味が分かりません。URLとは何のことを言っていますか？私の回答に書いたリンク先には普通にアクセスできると思いますが。

Comment: そしてこの回答の評価を下げた人は理由を教えてください。納得できません。

Comment: すみません。コメント先間違えてました。

Comment: 単にリンクのみを示した回答だと、リンク先が参照できなくなった場合にあなたの回答も価値を失ってしまいます。要点を引用するなどして、回答が自己完結している状態が望ましいです。 参考ヘルプ: [リンクの文脈を提示する | 良い回答を書くには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: それは望ましいかもしれませんが少なくとも現在は価値があるはずです。価値を失ったらその時マイナス投票すればよいのではないですか。